# Google chrome rendering an image with the wrong colors

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a jpeg file that will render with the wrong green color in google chrome.

This image:
[dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/573ny5a7q1lltmy/bg.jpg?dl=0), looks a lot brighter in chrome.

The icon generation in dropbox also reflects the error, theese are screenshots from the same dropbox page:

dropbox page, rendered in chrome, the image below should not be that bright:

[image: chrome rendition]

dropbox page, rendered in ie, images looks like they should:

[image: ie rendition]

To make this even more complicated, this stackoverflow page looks the same in all browsers. The image that looks the same in all browsers is here: [the other dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjszo4s25i26lkl/bakgrundsbild.jpg?dl=0)

Comment: Looks same to me, I don't see any issue

Comment: did you upload a similar image but that other color? Maybe a cache issue?

Comment: When I view that image in *any* browser, it is the bright green version. Perhaps you updated it, but the thumbnail was cached as the dull version for a time?

Comment: Might be subpixel-antialiasing issue? For me it is bright in FF and Chrome, and darker in IE, but it might also depend on screen ppi, and/or OS.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/579216/why-does-this-png-image-display-differently-in-chrome-firefox-than-in-safari-a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your image is in CMYK color mode. CMYK is a color format meant to print (paper) while app's, webs, etc use RGB. There are many colors you can't ever get in CMYK specially the brights (phosphorescent type). I guess chrome just try to convert the CMYK values to RGB by its own failing in this case.

Just open your image, turn it into RGB and try again. It will  look as you want. (when transforming from CMYK to RGB you won't notice any big diference. You will if you transform from RGB to CMYK though).

This is the image I download from boxdrop and transformed into RGB

[image]